# How do I know which DependencyProperty is related to a specific EffectiveValue index

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, dotmemory

I'm debugging a memory issue in a WPF application. Using [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) I have located an object instance in the effective values array of a DependencyObject.

[image]

I have the instance (effective value) and the index in the effective value array. Is it possible to find out which dependency property the value is related to?

Answer (score 1):

I suspected it was the [DataContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextproperty) dependency property and I could confirm it by running the application and looking at the [GlobalIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.globalindex) property of [DataContextProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextproperty) which matched the value in the field `_propertyIndex` of the `EffectiveValueEntry` in the `_effectiveValues` array.

However, without a hunch of which property to look for I guess I would have to use reflection to find every `DependencyObject` type and check every `GlobalIndex` property for a match.